# How to use backup database when main database is down ? (failover mechanics)

Tags: database, go, failover

Our system flow is like this and for simplicity please pardon the code structure

```golang
func main() {

    // conn is dbpool
    conn := getConnection()
    router := newRouter(conn)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3333", router)
}

func newConnection() *sql.DB {

    // make new connection, pretend has failover function
    // if database A is down, then connect to database B
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://user:pass@localhost/bookstore")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db
}

func newRouter(db *sql.DB) http.Handler {

    // db is passed to the router handler

    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })

        // do something with db inside handler
        if err != nil {
            // it shall use backup connection in here

        }

    })

    return r
}
```

the code structure reference is from here : https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access
which i think is a modification of "Wrapping The Connection Pool"

nothing fancy on the main function. It get dbpool connection from getConnection() function. Then get a handler from newRouter function with previous dbpool arguments. Then finally we start http server with the handler.

the problem is when the main database is down, then inside the err shall connect to backup database. But dbpool is passed from the main function, and to update the dbpool, then i need to update the handler and updating again the http server.

we raise some temporary solutions to define 2 connection at the beginning, pass the 2 pool to the router, and use backup connection pool when main pool is down.

```
func main() {

    // conn is dbpool
    conn := getConnection()
    backupConn := getBackupConnection()
    router := newRouter(conn,backupConn)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":3333", router)
}

func newRouter(db *sql.DB, backupDb *sql.DB) http.Handler {

    // db is passed to the router handler

    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })

        // do something with db inside handler
        if err != nil {
            // it shall use backup connection in here
            backupDb.Exec()
            // use backup db
        }

    })

    return r
}
```

Is this a best practice / any other solutions to tackle this problems ? thanks

Best regards